# Waiting for JSON response to finish before updating fields

Tags: java, android, json

Currently in my application I execute a JSONDownloader, then tell my application to wait for a set period of time before updating fields with the retrieved data. How do I go about making the application wait for the JSONDownloader to finish its' task before I update the fields?

The JSONDowloader class is written (abridged) as follows and is run as an asynchronous activity. This class is called when needed and sets global variables which, after a set amount of time after being called are updated. I'd like the fields to be updated as soon as the class has finished running.

```
public class JSONDownloader extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        if(JSONstate == false){
            try {
                final URL url = new URL("https://irrelevant");

                final URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                urlConnection.connect();
                final InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    sb.append((char) inputStream.read());
                }
                System.out.println("up to setting string");
                String result = sb.toString();

                JSONObject jsonOrg = new JSONObject(result);

                String ok = "ok";

                Response = jsonOrg.getString("response");
                System.out.println(Response);

                if(Response.equals(ok)){
                    Settingsresponse = true;

                    orgName = jsonOrg.getString("orgName");
                    System.out.println("orgName" + orgName);
                    accessPointName = jsonOrg.getString("accessPointName");
                    System.out.println("accessPointName" + accessPointName);
                    lat = jsonOrg.getString("latitude");
                    System.out.println("lat" + lat);
                    longi = jsonOrg.getString("longitude");
                    System.out.println("longi" + longi);
                    floor = jsonOrg.getString("floor");
                    System.out.println("floor" + floor);
                    orgId = jsonOrg.getString("orgId");
                    System.out.println("orgId" + orgId);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Data sent was erroneous");
                    Settingsresponse = false;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.print(e);      
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    }
}
```

The JSONDownloader is called within whatever method it is needed and then immediately after this is called; currently a set time is used before updating fields as thus:

```
public void waitthencall()
{
    long t0,t1;
    t0=System.currentTimeMillis();
    do{
        t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    while (t1-t0<2000);

    setfields();
}
```

Comment: First what is JSONDownloader, it's obvious from the name of the class but that's not a library I presume it's custom built class we need to see. Second I presume you execute the JSONDownloader task as AsyncTask and not on the UI thread so you can check if the thread has completed and do your actions once all is done. Show more code so we can help.

Comment: Edit made: JSONDownloader class shown.

Comment: Do the rest inside `    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    }`.

Comment: This does not work. The method is not run if called from here.

Answer (score 1):

you need a Callback listener to update your UI. [Example](http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Setting+Up+a+Callback+Function+in+Android)

Create a callback listener and implement it inside your activity or from where you are updating the UI.

Answer (score 0):

By using asynchronous task!

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

May help!

Comment: The code is already running as an asynchronous activity. The issue is finding a way of only running the follow up code once JSONDownloader has finished running.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, the method onPostExecute is call once doInBackGround has completed processing call your method from there, it will assure you that doInBackGround has finished its execution